# Using aluminium enclosure as heat sink

Tags: safety, mains, grounding

Can I use the aluminium enclosure of my mains powered product as a heatsink?

I'm thinking about mounting TO-220 transistors pressed against the enclosure, to get away with passive cooling by using the large surface of my product's aluminium enclosure as a heat sink. I'd use transistors with insulated tabs.

However, I worry this isn't really safe. The IEC-60950-1 stipulates that the product must be safe even under a single fault.

I believe this requirement would be fulfilled on paper. If the insulation between the transistor and the housing fails, the product would be short circuited to ground which would immediately blow a fuse. I can arrange to have the resistance in the ground much smaller than the resistance through the rest of the product, so even the transient voltage of the housing should be safe.

However, I worry that it might be hard to get the aluminium box properly grounded. I'm thinking that a grounding wire would be attached to the housing using screws. But how reliable would such an connection be, electrically? Could aluminium oxide accumulate over time, increasing the resistance to unsafe levels?

Edit: I might need to clarify that of course the housing of the product is earthed. It is the reliability of this earthing bond that worries me.

Comment: The metal/aluminum chassis of your mains powered enclosure will usually be grounded anyhow for a class I device (unless you're going for somewhat unusual, but not impossible class II device).

Comment: There are plenty of audio amplifiers that do exactly this, with exposed heat sinks.

Comment: What in your product converts an unsafe voltage to a safe voltage and is the transistor on the safe side?

Comment: The transistor is on the unsafe side. All the power stuff in the circuit is on the mains-side.

Comment: Fluff: Yes, of course the housing is earthed. It's just the reliability of this bond that worries me.

Comment: EJP: Interesting! But I guess their power parts are at <50V, meaning that they don't really have to be insulated for safety. Or do power amps output more than 50V?

Comment: It sounds like it would be similar to single insulation in a mains-powered motor with metal case bolted to a grounded housing, so probably it could be approved, but I don't think the TO220 insulated package would provide nearly enough creepage distance. Maybe you'd have to put an additional insulator under the transistors.

Comment: Spehro: Ah,good point! I'd need to provide basic insulation (if I understand the rules correctly - the device is grounded after all), and that means 2mm of clearance - not really feasible using TO220. And neither is 3.5mm creepage.

Comment: Actually, investigating this a bit more, I think 2mm clearance is exactly what you get with a TO220 mounted against a heat sink, and 3.5mm creepage is also achievable by using a suitable isolation pad behind the TO-220, like this one: https://www.elfa.se/elfa3~en_gb/elfa/init.do?item=75-654-19&toc=20455 .

Comment: @Spehro Pefhany: Looking for example a cheap ATX PSU: the heatsink for the HV side TO220's is not connected to anything else on the PCB (separate pads), but the heatsink on the LV side is connected to the ground (which is in turn connected to the case). So it depends what potential the TO220's are at. It's not said in avl_sweden's application/post what potential they're at.

Comment: They're connected to live 230V mains voltage. So, peak is above 300V.

Comment: Ok, in that case what you should probably look at to gain some inspiration from are passively cooled ATX power supplies. These are rare as only diehard super-silent-PC freaks buy them; but they use the case as radiator (at least for the secondary, I suspect). See https://pcpartpicker.com/part/rosewill-power-supply-silentnight500 for example. I don't have any of those to look at myself, but you might be able to find some teardowns/peak-insides somewhere on the web.

Comment: Here's (rather old) video, alas not on youtube: http://realestate.aol.com/blog/videos/green-living/147836124/ jump to a bit more than half way in to see inside: basically the inner heatsinks are thermally connected to the outer one (case) via large thermal pads, which I presume provide enough electrical isolation.

Comment: Also, you can get high insulation with thick washers as you assumed, for 1000V you need 6mm; the [NXP TO-220 mounting guide](http://www.nxp.com/documents/application_note/AN11172.pdf) has some more detailed schematics, angles etc. in the last couple of pages. But it seems you can't get that with clip mounts, only with screw...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> Could aluminium oxide accumulate over time, increasing the resistance to unsafe levels?

There are some precautions to could be taken like coating the aluminum screw point with Alnox right after scrubbing it but before making the connection. This is up to US Gov standards http://www.usbr.gov/power/data/fist/fist3_3/vol3-3.pdf (see chapter 6).

Comment: Here's a similar product (Penetrox A) more easily available in the EU/UK: http://www.gcaltd.co.uk/shop/lightning-protection/ic08--8oz-tube/